# Unable to calculate limit without getting an indeterminate form

Tags: limits

I initially need to solve this:
$$\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{e^{-1/x}}{x^k},\; \text{ where }k\in\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}.$$

When I substitute $y=\dfrac1x$ then I get:
$\lim\limits_{y\to\infty} \dfrac{y^k}{e^y} $

I'm unable to calculate this limit. Whatever I do, I get an indeterminate limit, even with L'Hospital's rule

Comment: How many times have you differentiated?

Comment: @Hadi Your edit replaced $e^{\color{red}{-}1/x}$ with $e^{1/x}$. Destructive ;)

Comment: @metamorphy ohhhh I'm sorry about that. The answer should be 0 then. I'll delete my previous answer and add a new one if you'd like, or I could explain it here in the comments.

Comment: @Hadi: I've brought the "$-$" back. Answer (new or edited) is the right place.

Comment: @metamorphy I've edited my answer. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $k\neq0$ we have $$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{e^{-1/x}}{x^k}$$
$$=\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{1}{e^{1/x}x^k}$$
$$=\left(\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{1}{e^{1/x}}\right)\left(\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{1}{x^k}\right)$$
$$=\left(\frac{1}{e^{\infty}}\right)\left({\frac{1}{\infty^k}}\right)$$
$$=0\times0$$
$$=0$$

In the case where $k=0$ we'd get the same answer since the expression becomes $$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0^+}{e^{-1/x}}=e^{-\infty}=0.$$

Therefore $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{e^{-1/x}}{x^k}=0$ for all $k\in\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}$.

Comment: Use \left(\right)

Comment: @ms._VerkhovtsevaKatya thank you!

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: Thanks a lot, but are you sure that this is right? The solution should be zero!

Comment: @smalllearner I think so. If you graph the function you can see that it tends to infinity when it approaches 0 from the right (unless I need to touch up on my left-right sided limits). Is the 0 answer part of your instructor’s/textbook’s answer?

Answer (score 0):

Let compute the limit of its logarithm.

$$\lim_{y\to+\infty}(k\ln(y)-y)$$

which becomes

$$\lim_{y\to+\infty}y(k\frac{\ln(y)}{y}-1)=-\infty$$

so, your limit is zero.